# Rails compare time column with now

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time

Quick question.

I have the following within a view

```
<tbody>

    <% @courses.each do |course| %>
      <% if course.lec_exam.eql?("LEC")%>
      <tr class ="text-center">
        <td><%= course.location %></td>

        <% if (Time.now > course.begin_time && Time.now < course.end_time)
          course.status = 'Taken'
        else
          course.status ='Open'
          end %>
        <td><%= course.status %></td>
        <td><%= course.begin_time %></td>
        <td><%= course.end_time %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit Status', edit_course_path(course) %></td>
      </tr>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

I tested this and begin_time always equates to true and end_time always equates to false. For reference, my DB stores the columns via the following. If it makes a difference, the values are imported via CSV.

```
t.time     "begin_time"
t.time     "end_time"
```

Some example begin_time and end_time values:

```
2000-01-01 10:30:00 UTC     2000-01-01 11:20:00 UTC

2000-01-01 11:30:00 UTC     2000-01-01 12:20:00 UTC
```

So I can see why begin_time equates to true and why end_time equates to false. Why do the values have a date associated with them when they're only stored as times, both in the CSV and DB? In the CSV they're stored as 10:30 AM, 11:20 AM, etc.

Any pointers? Anything obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should move your logic to your model.
Second, the Rails :time datatype still stores a date into the database (even though it isn't used). We'll have to manually strip the date:

```
Class Course < ActiveRecord::Base

  def status
    t = Time.now.utc.strftime("%H%M%S%N")
    end_time_f = self.end_time.utc.strftime("%H%M%S%N")
    begin_time_f = self.begin_time.utc.strftime("%H%M%S%N")

    ’if (t >= begin_time_f && (t <= end_time_f)
      status = 'Taken'
    else
      status = 'Open'
    end
    return status
  end
end
```

Then in your view you can simply call `course.status`

Comment: Thank you. However, the status still always returns open because t is never less than self.end_time.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Utilized answer above, as well as the 'tod' gem, which provides a to_time_of_day method for both Time and DateTime.

```
def status
 t = Time.now.to_time_of_day
 bt = self.begin_time.to_time_of_day
 et = self.end_time.to_time_of_day
 if (t >= bt) && (t<=et)
   status = 'Taken'
 else
   status = 'Open'
 end
 return status
end
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I was almost using those exact lines. I just wasn't using the .utc method